# Looping through Mongo Results in NodeJS and adding field or using virtuals

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm somewhat new to Node and MongoDB and I'm running into a really odd problem. I'm trying to add a new field to a json being printed out from a MongoDB. But for whatever reason, it doesn't show up. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Here is an example

```
app.Event.find({},['_id','dateStart']).where('status').equals(1).where('dateStart').gte(searchDate).sort('dateStart', -1).exec(function(err, events) {
    for (var i=0; i< events.length; i++){
        var url = 'http://localhost/' + events[i]._id;
        events[i].url = url;

        //Printing here does not show the new URL
        console.log('Looking at event... ' + events[i]);

        //But printing here does show it...
        console.log('Address should be ' + events[i].url);
    }

    //And printing here does not as either...
    res.json(events);
});
```

I know that I can add the field to my schema, which isn't really what I want. When I add a virtual field URL to my schema, I still don't see it in the results:

```
Event.virtual('url').get(function() {
    return 'http://localhost/' + this._id;
});

Event.set('toJSON', {
    virtuals: true
});

Event.set('toObject', {
    virtuals: true
});
```

Comment: Is there data? Use the console to verify.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution with the virtual should work, provided that you create the model *after* you created the virtual on the schema (which is named the same as your model, correct?).

So this doesn't work:

```
var Schema = new mongoose.Schema(...);
var Model  = mongoose.model('Model', Schema);
Schema.virtual('url').get(...);
```

But this should:

```
var Schema = new mongoose.Schema(...);
Schema.virtual('url').get(...);
var Model  = mongoose.model('Model', Schema);
```

(the configuration of `toJSON` and `toObject` are still required)